Making chart with variable data start column
I'm trying to make a chart with a dynamic range based on the FIND of specific text in a column from a range (data series by months). I need a chart of the data for the current and previous two months.
The idea is to find the column with the current month and use it and the previous two columns for chart data. However, I can't get the data for the prior two months.
Sub Chart()
    '
    ' Chart Macro
    '
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim SC As Range
    Dim EC As Range
      
    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="March-2024", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    Set SC = ra.Offset(0, -3)
    Set EC = ra.Offset(1, 0)
    
    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Charts!$B$1:$B$2,SC:EC")
    End If
End Sub

The problem is the part with SC:EC which are not accepted as ranges.
It should find the start cell and data range for the chart to be set three columns back and one row below it.

Specify the Chart manually with the Macro Recorder switched on use the code it generates and adapt it and go from there

I did it and I tried to replace the second part (which is SC:EC in my code). The problem is that the data series names and data cells are not consecutive ranges (data series name in is B1:B1 but the data cells are O1:Q2). From this point the code doesn't work

As far as I know SC:EC is not a valid Range. Here are a couple of examples from a chart of mine that works. Data Series Name (a single cell with a text value) ='2292006164 - 2024-04-25'!$AC$1 and my Data Series Values (a column of data values to plot) ='2292006164 - 2024-04-25'!$AC$2:$AC$291

SC:EC should be the range defined from the variables SC (start column) and EC (End Column) which are declared already but that's the point - VBA accepts them as a column names and not as the variables already set. And this is where I don't know how to define the range properly.

Specify your Source Data Range something like this - sChartDataRangeText = "Charts!$B$1:$B$2," & SC & ":" & EC and see if that helps. Currently Excel is seeing your variable names as column headings.

To define multiple non-contiguous ranges for a Range object the string of the ranges must be comma separated and the 2 range objects Address property to use something like this:
Range("Charts!$B$1:$B$2," & "Charts!" & SC.address & ":" & EC.address)
Since it will be used for a Chart this result range must be formate a rectangle.
